# Different compilers, different syntax

Tags: c++

How to compensate the differences between the syntax of different compilers of the same programming language? How could I know which one is standard and used worldwide to make projects? 
For example: I worked 4 months on Borland C++ compiler to learn C++ but now I saw the syntax of Borland, Visual C++ and Developer C++ is different. I am confused, need some guidance...

Comment: Please give an example where the syntax is different

Comment: Use conditional compilation: #ifdef, etc.

Comment: Not all compilers (e.g. Borland C++) are compliant to support the current c++ standard.

Comment: Note that the C++ language is still evolving (C++11, C++14, C++17 and more) .  Also one of the compilers you listed above was last updated 17 years ago (Boreland C++).  Dealing with standard and implementation differences is just part of the job of being a programmer.

Comment: Which software should I follow to get up to the current programming standards for C++??

Comment: use upto date compilers instead of ancient ones, newer version of either gcc, clang or vs c++ compiler will do fine. The newest syntax is where you don't put .h in header files while including, eg - `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std` too.

Comment: The de facto standard of the C++ language that determines what must be portable across all compliant compilers is the **ISO C++ Standard**. You can buy a copy of the latest standard here: https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: Alternative: Go back in time to a C++ standard to which all the compilers conform. Also tricky as the more recent compilers are just as likely to have deprecated and removed functionality that was found to be flawed. When I had to simultaneously support multiple compilers I found the biggest issues were with c-style string formatting. For one thing, everyone disagreed on how to printf a 64 bit integer. This shouldn't be a problem with C++. Where the compilers disagree, go to the lowest common denominator or build a wrapper so you can confine  the differences to a few source files.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is to not use parts which are specific to one compiler or another. Before you use a feature of the language, check on the internet to see if it's specific to any one compiler. If it is, then don't use it.

Other than that, actually making a C/C++ program which is compilable by different compilers is a task which takes effort. It doesn't "just happen", because the compilers each have their own quirks, their own level of support of the standard etc. Even writing compliant C99/C++11 code you might still see issues. So one solution is to actually compile the program with different compilers on a regular basis (say, as part of testing before pushing code to the central repository) and make sure that all of them can compile the code, and the resulting software can run.

As for "standard" compilers, on Linux and Mac gcc and clang can be considered "gold". On Windows, the compilers by Microsoft are standard.

Comment: thanks alot, u mean Visual C++ is standard compiler rite nw to work on??

Comment: @AsimShehzad that depends entirely on what you plan to do with the code. If you require portability, conform to a C++ Standard supported by the compilers available to the supported systems and add implementation specific wrappers to handle the differences where you must. If portability is not an issue only then can you select a particular compiler implementation as your baseline, but pray you never have to port the software.